# Import multiple excel spreadsheets to sharepoint 2010 lists

Tags: 2010, excel, import, spreadsheet

I have a user asking if its possible to import an excel file with multiple spreadsheets to a SharePoint 2010 solution? Each spreadsheet should be turned into one list. 
It is an autogenerated excel file with 10-15 spreadsheets, and today they have to save each spreadsheet as a new excel file and import the files one by one which is very time consuming. 
Is there any easier solution without the need of coding?
Thank you!

Comment: There might be a third party add-on that can do this for you. I don't know of any way you could do this out of the box without code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways (apart from .NET code) how to import spreadsheets into SharePoint using PowerShell. If, of course, PowerShell doesn't mean coding for you:

1. Convert each sheet into separate CSV file and use a PS script similar to this one:

> ```
> $InvFile="file.csv"
> $FileExists = (Test-Path $InvFile -PathType Leaf)
> if ($FileExists) {
>   $tblData = import-csv $InvFile
>
>   foreach ($row in $tblData) { 
>       $columnValue = $row."Project Code".ToString() 
>   }
> }
> ```

2. Use Excel com object to open the spreadsheet. This will require Excel installed on the computer you are running the script on:

`$FilePath = "C:\file.xlsx"
 $SheetName = "BuildSpecs"
 $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
 $objExcel.Visible = $false
 $WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
 $WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName)`

and then get the data by using:

```
 $worksheet.Range("C3").Text $worksheet.Range("C3:C3").Text
 $worksheet.Range("C3","C3").Text $worksheet.cells.Item(3, 3).text
 $worksheet.cells.Item(3, 3).value2
 $worksheet.Columns.Item(3).Rows.Item(3).Text
 $worksheet.Rows.Item(3).Columns.Item(3).Text
 $worksheet.UsedRange.Range("c3").Text
```

There are plenty of tutorials on the web how to open lists and add new items in PowerShell. For example [here](http://sharepointrelated.com/2012/05/03/addedit-list-items-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010/).

Hope this helps.